# Adding New Artifact Types and New Record to Artifact Types in WSO2 Gov. Reg 4.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am getting an error when adding a new record to a new artifact type I created. The error is as follows

**failed to add/edit artifact details. A valid qualified name was not set for this artifact**

I created a new artifact type called 'Domain'. The artifact type was added but I cannot add new records to it. Get the same error as above when I add new record to Domain artifact type. My xml is attached.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-domain+xml" shortName="domain" singularLabel="Domain" pluralLabel="Domains" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="9">
<storagePath>/domains/@{overview_domain}/@{overview_parentname}/domain</storagePath>
<nameAttribute>overview_domain</nameAttribute>
<ui>
<list>
    <column name="Domain">
        <data type="text" value="overview_domain"/>
    </column>
    <column name="Parent Domain">
        <data type="text" value="overview_parentname"/>
    </column>            
</list>
</ui>
<content>
<table name="Domain">
<field type="options" required="true">
    <name label="Domain Name">Domain Name</name>
    <values>
        <value>Research</value> 
        <value>Development</value> 
        <value>Medicine</value> 
        <value>Marketing and Sales</value> 
        <value>Operations</value> 
        <value>Enabling Functions</value>
        <value>Communications</value> 
        <value>Human Resources</value> 
        <value>Finance</value> 
        <value>Legal</value> 
        <value>Purchasing</value> 
        <value>Information Systems</value>
    </values>
</field>
<field type="options">
    <name label="Parent Domain Name">Parent Domain Name</name>
    <values>
        <value/>
        <value>Research</value> 
        <value>Development</value> 
        <value>Medicine</value> 
        <value>Marketing and Sales</value> 
        <value>Operations</value> 
        <value>Enabling Functions</value>
        <value>Communications</value> 
        <value>Human Resources</value> 
        <value>Finance</value> 
        <value>Legal</value> 
        <value>Purchasing</value> 
        <value>Information Systems</value>
    </values>
</field>        
</table>
</content>
</artifactType>
```

Also I want to know if there is a thorough document describing how to add artifact types and records. As an example I added a storage path called

/domains/@{overview_domain}/@{overview_parentname}/domain

but I do not know where this points to and if this is even valid or not. The documentation in the online help is not adequate enough to add new artifact structures and records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Under the `<ui>` tag you have listed two columns. The value attribute given to each column must be in the format {basetable}_{fieldname}

Therefor the names given under each `<field>` must match with the value `<data attribute=` of corresponding `<column>` under `<ui>`.

To get rid of the error, change the name of the first field to be "Domain" so that it matches with the name that you have given in the column(i.e. overview_domain). So that the  tag of the first  should look like

```
<name label="Domain Name">Domain</name>
```

You should do the same for the second field too, so that the  of second field must look as follows

```
<name label="Parent Domain Name">ParentName</name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find the corrected domain.rxt.

To create your own RXTs please find [this article](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/03/how-to-create-new-artifacts-type-in.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-domain+xml" shortName="domain" singularLabel="Domain" pluralLabel="Domains" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="9">
<storagePath>/domains/@{overview_domain}/@{overview_parentname}/domain</storagePath>
<nameAttribute>overview_domain</nameAttribute>
<ui>
<list>
    <column name="Domain">
        <data type="text" value="overview_domain"/>
    </column>
    <column name="Parent Domain">
        <data type="path" value="overview_parentname" href="@{storagePath}"/>
    </column>            
</list>
</ui>
<content>
<table name="Overview">
<field type="options" required="true">
    <name label="Domain Name">domain</name>
    <values>
        <value>Research</value> 
        <value>Development</value> 
        <value>Medicine</value> 
        <value>Marketing and Sales</value> 
        <value>Operations</value> 
        <value>Enabling Functions</value>
        <value>Communications</value> 
        <value>Human Resources</value> 
        <value>Finance</value> 
        <value>Legal</value> 
        <value>Purchasing</value> 
        <value>Information Systems</value>
    </values>
</field>
<field type="options">
    <name label="Parent Domain Name">parentname</name>
    <values>
        <value/>
        <value>Research</value> 
        <value>Development</value> 
        <value>Medicine</value> 
        <value>Marketing and Sales</value> 
        <value>Operations</value> 
        <value>Enabling Functions</value>
        <value>Communications</value> 
        <value>Human Resources</value> 
        <value>Finance</value> 
        <value>Legal</value> 
        <value>Purchasing</value> 
        <value>Information Systems</value>
    </values>
</field>        
</table>
</content>
</artifactType>
```